# How can I set up a Spring Boot Validator that can use 2x items passed but the requirement is one of either value?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-validator

Our restful service is setup to accept `"vendorOrderReference":"Create Order Postman"` but business has now decided they want to change the word **vendor** to **client** (facepalm) so it would now be `"clientOrderReference":"Create Order Postman"`. The problem is the Spring Validator is set up with

```
@NotBlank(message = "{createOrderRequest.vendorOrderReference.required}")
private String vendorOrderReference;
```

I've been trying to figure out how can I check if the endpoint gets the property **vendorOrderReference** or **clientOrderReference** and just use the one passed for `private String vendorOrderReference;`

Basically abstract the property label so I don't have the nightmare cascade in the code base business's "simple request" is causing.

I looked into existing annotations and tried to figure out how to create custom ones but I've had no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use @JsonAlias to ensure it's mapped using either or property value vendorOrderReference or createOrderReference coupled with the @NotBlank message?

I think this might meet your requirements from the sound of the above?

Comment: Never heard of it :) I'll look into it.